# Angularjs and routeParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a piece of code that is getting JSON data from a local server. I am trying to display those data into a page and then when i'll click on a product i want to see the details of it. So far i can display all my products into a page but when i'm heading to the details page i got an error Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Can you please help me out?

This is my code so far.

app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', []).
config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when("/", {templateUrl: "/partials/products.html"}).
        when("/details/:id", {templateUrl: "/partials/details.html", controller: DetailsCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: "/"});
})


function AppCtrl($scope, $http){
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/products/727617361726372')
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.productList = data;

        /*$scope.filterProductsByCategory = function(category){
            $scope.search = category
        };*/
    })
    .error(function(data){
        console.log("Error!: ");
    });
}

function DetailsCtrl($scope, $routeParams){
   $scope.item = $scope.productList[$routeParams.id];
}
```

details.html

```
<h2>This is the details pages</h2>
product id: {{ item.product_id }}
<br/>
product name: {{ item.product_name}}
```

index.html

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1 class="text-danger">Welcome to our Store</h1>
    <hr/>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

products.html

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="product in productList">
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="img/img3.jpeg">
    <div class="caption">
        <h4><a href="#/details/{{product.product_id}}">{{ product.product_name }}</a></h3>
        <p>Category: {{ product.category_name }} ({{ product.category_id }})</p>
        <p class="text-muted">{{ product.product_details}}</p>
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>
                <p class="product-price btn">&euro; {{ product.product_price }}</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the `productList` in your `AppCtrl`. If you want to access a specific item in your `DetailsCtrl` you'll need to get the specific item  since you can't access `AppCtrl` scope variables in another Ctrl.

The best way to do this would be to create an extra rest call for getting a single item.

A quick way to fix your code, although I really **don't** recommend it would be to use `$rootcope` in your `AppCtrl`

I'd suggest reading Angular Docs on $scope. It might give you a better understanding how scopes work in angular:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have injected ngRoute correctly.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
```

Other than that there is nothing wrong with your code.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/4XXbdBdjULlM0760wSI1)

Just check your code again.